# Auto Download PDF thru URLDownloadToFile

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

How do I pull the default name of a PDF from a website instead of blah.pdf in following code?

```
Option Explicit 

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _ 
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _ 
ByVal pCaller As Long, _ 
ByVal szURL As String, _ 
ByVal szFileName As String, _ 
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _ 
ByVal lpfnCB As Long _ 
) As Long 

Sub z() 

    Dim strSource As String 
    Dim strDest As String 
    strSource = "http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf" 
    strDest = "c:\temp\blah.pdf" 
    URLDownloadToFile 0, strSource, strDest, 0, 0 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your original method of downloading the file is fine, but how are you actually determining the path and filename?  Do you have a list?  Do you need to get it from the website?  With regards to retrieving the instrument number, first set references (VBE > Tools > References) to Microsoft XML, vx.0 and Microsoft HTML Object Library, then change the specified URL accordingly, and then try...

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInstrumentNumber()

    'Set a reference (VBE > Tools > References) to the following libraries:
    '   1) Microsoft XML, v6.0 (or whatever version you have)
    '   2) Microsoft HTML Object Library

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sInstrument As String

    sURL = "http://www.cran.r-project.org/..." 'change the URL adddress accordingly

    With XMLReq
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Error " & XMLReq.Status & ":  " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    sInstrument = HTMLDoc.getElementById("6063270").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).Cells(0).innerText
    sInstrument = Trim(Split(sInstrument, ":")(1))

    MsgBox "Instrument number:  " & sInstrument, vbInformation

    Set XMLReq = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah, it's working..!! it's taking id number instead of instrument. I want that instrument number as that PDF name.

Comment: Here is the HTML Code of that link

Comment: <table  class="detail-table" id="6063270"><tbody><tr><td  valign="TOP" colspan="1"><b>Instrument: </b><a onclick="notify('ViewImage=201707030027817');event.preventDefault();" href="#">201707030027817</a></td><td valign="TOP" <b>Volume Page: </b>201707030027817</td></tr><tr><td " valign="TOP" colspan="1"><b>Recorded: </b>7/3/2017 2:47:41 PM</td><td 
<tr style="visibility: collapse;"><td><div id="InstrumentReferenceId" style="visibility: hidden;">6063270</div></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post to include a method of retrieving the instrument number.

Comment: it's asking to define HTMLDoc

Comment: Thank you for you support, it seems I am applying wrong code.

Comment: Is there any way to auto save the PDF files from View downloads (Ctrl+J) window in internet explorer (version 11) instead of clicking save button for each and every PDF.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have added a comment to let you know that I've edited my post.  Still knew here at StackOverflow.

Comment: How can we write macro to get page numbers of PDF document. (Web link PDF document)